# sql script needs if statement wrapped

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i'm trying to wrap a simple function within an a check for existence why am i getting incorrect syntax?

**updated:**

```
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Customers)
    BEGIN
        USE [rstestDB]

        SET ANSI_NULLS ON

        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

        CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetName] 
        (
            @p1 nvarchar(25)
        )
        RETURNS varchar
        AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Result varchar(25)
            SELECT @Result = 'John Doe'
            RETURN @Result
        END
    END
GO
```

Getting following error:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FUNCTION'.
Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Comment: you're trying to set `'John Doe'` into an `INT`

Comment: thanks, updated. but there is still a problem with it. does it have something to do with the GO's ? If you remove the IF check, BEGIN, and end the script works fine. it's not until i introduce the check for exists

Comment: @rod it does, please look at my answer below.

Comment: varchar and nvarchar should always have length arguments, e.g. varchar(30). Otherwise they could default to varchar(1) in some contexts and varchar(30) in others.

Comment: @JohnDewey: they default to a length of 1 - except in `CAST` or `CONVERT` where they default to 30

Comment: @marc_s Correct; I am simply suggesting a best practice.

Comment: @JohnDewey: yes, I totally agree with you and support your recommendation for the best practice of always specifying an explicit length. Your statement just wasn't awfully clear on when the length defaults to 1 (*some contexts*) or 30 (*others*) - that's what I was trying to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`GO` is a batch separator.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

GO is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities that send commands to the SQL engine, it's not valid SQL.

Take out all the `GO`s except for at the very end.

A simpler example that will also fail:

```
IF 1=1
BEGIN
 SELECT 'FOO'
 GO
END
```

All your settings should really be at the very beginning of the script since they will persist for the length of the session.